# Tomcat not find correctely spring-boot project

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a `spring-boot` project which is deployed on tomcat8 on my ubuntu server.
Yesterday after a restart, my project seems not work anymore.

I got this error:

```
   HTTP Status 404 - /
   type Status report
   message /
   description The requested resource is not available.
   Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
```

I tried to redeploy my project, I don't have any error for deploying my war.
I tried to reinstall tomcat, but it's didn't work (I don't have any error, or log error for deploying but still got HTTP 404 when I'm checking at URL).

Any advice is helpful. Thanks (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: what did you restarted? Tomcat? Ubuntu? Check if the war is in your tomcat deploy folder

Comment: I restarted my Tomcat, my tomcat can deploy other war's project. But when I try to deploy a simple HelloWord SpringBoot project, I got HTTP status 404.
I check in webapps folder, the project is deployed but i don't know why I can't access to it

Comment: maybe just your request url is wrong? You have to provide more infos about your request and which url the application listens

Comment: I checked it too, I try to deploy with my tomcat in local. It's working for all projects, but I don't know what it s happen to my tomcat (ubuntu).

Comment: My mistake, when I reinstall tomcat I forgot to set JavaPath version 8 for my tomcat. Thanks for your help Patrick